# MPlayer-vaapi shows artifacts while playing H264 stream

Tags: intel-graphics, video-streaming, vaapi

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Surface pro 3 and I have installed `i965-va-driver` and `libva-intel-vaapi-driver` to take advantage of vaapi driver for video acceleration decoding.
Then I have installed `mplayer-vaapi` as suggested on this link:

[Vaapi not working in Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/302759/vaapi-not-working-in-ubuntu-13-04)

Using `vaapi` driver to decode and play `h264` stream, mplayer shows artifacts about once every 5 to 10 sec, as a partially "green frame" (frame with a green stripe across it, of varying height, sometimes most of the frame, sometimes much less). 
MPlayer log shows messages e.g. "RTP: missed 2 packets".
I also noticed that with vaapi enabled, I cannot use multithreading with libavcodec (lavdopts threads=N), from forum discussions this seems expected. In that case, what else can I do to increase RTP receive and H.264 decode speed?

My MPlayer command line:

```
mplayer -vo vaapi -va vaapi -benchmark -v -msglevel all=9 br60.sdp
```

Thank you,
Harshal Patel
HPC Systems Engineer
Signalogic Inc.

Image displaying artifacts:
[image]

Image displaying error messages:
[image]

---

### Update to the question:

I used command `cat /proc/net/udp` and it showed me result,

```
sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode ref pointer drops                  
 1235: 00000000:B000 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 57854 2 ffff8800a5b35e00 4256
```

Here, drop packets = 4256

So whenever I see artifacts on MPlayer, I am seeing drops packet counter getting increased whether I use vaapi or multi-threaded x86 decoder.

How can I prevent Linux Network Stack from dropping frames? Is there Ubuntu driver upgrade or patch for this?

Surface tablet was connected to internet using WiFi, If I connect it with LAN, I am not seeing any packet loss or any artifacts while playing the stream.

So how can I increase Wireless throughput on tablet?

### NOTE:

I am using VAAPI for -vo(video output) and -va(video acceleration) in MPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

I also see MPlayer artifacts streaming 720p to a Surface Pro 3 with Ubuntu 14.04 installed, but without using vaapi, instead using -lavdopts threads=4 (x86 multithreaded H.264 decode). The artifact is not a "green frame", but looks like it occurs with similar rate and frame position as described.

I was able to get improved results by turning off Network Manager, as noted here:

[How can I completely remove NetworkManager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249944/how-can-i-completely-remove-networkmanager)

I first noticed this because every 30 sec, or sometimes every 1 minute or 2 minutes, the entire Surface user interface would lock up for a few sec... the interval varied, yet it was not random either. That led me to investigate WiFi scanning... which led to Network Manager.

(My apologies if this answer shows twice.  I first posted it two (2) weeks ago and it still has not appeared.  I hope it's not due to the effect of NetworkManager on RTP video streaming.  I realize there is some debate among Ubuntu developers regarding whether disabling of NetworkManager should be a do-able thing or not, but please don't blame me, I'm just a messenger).